# Error with Soundex: cannot find symbol

Tags: java, soundex

Getting the following error:

> error: cannot find symbol so = **S**oundex.parse(s, true);

```
public static List<String> getSimilar(String s) 
{
    List<String> simWords = new LinkedList<>();

    // Find uppercase and lowercase Soundex ID for letters
    String so;
    if (Character.isLetter(s.charAt(0))) {
        so = Soundex.parse(s, true);
        if (dictionary.containsKey(so)) simWords.addAll(dictionary.get(so));
        so = Soundex.parse(s, false);
        if (dictionary.containsKey(so)) simWords.addAll(dictionary.get(so));
    }
    else {
        so = Soundex.parse(s);
        if (dictionary.containsKey(so)) simWords.addAll(dictionary.get(so));
    }

    return simWords;
}
```

I've got a `Soundex.java` in the same folder as this file and within that the class is named `Soundex` and the method is below:

```
static String parse(String s, boolean uppercase) {
    Soundex sx = new Soundex(s);
    if (uppercase) {
        sx.code[0] = Character.toUpperCase(sx.code[0]);
    } else {
        sx.code[0] = Character.toLowerCase(sx.code[0]);
    }
    return new String(sx.code);
}
```

Comment: It looks like the compiler is complaining about Soundex.parse(s, true);  But then I'm not positive that's a compiler message or your paraphrasing of it.  However I do notice a few lines down that you're calling parse() with just one parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I can see you are calling two methods,

```
 so = Soundex.parse(s);
so = Soundex.parse(s, true);
```

but according to method defintion,only

```
static String parse(String s, boolean uppercase)
```

mthod signature exist. Please check if first method with one arguement exist.

Comment: yes there is a method which accepts one argument.

static String parse(String s) {
        return new String(new Soundex(s).code);
    }